# Sort nested Array of objects by date

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of users objects with several key value pairs, and I wanted to sort users base on createdAt that in chatInfo array

```
[
    {
        _id: "1",
        age: "30",
        chatInfo: [
            {
                chatId: "22",
                createdAt: "2020-07-07T00:39:30.571Z",
                seen: false,
                senderEmail: "debot73186@klefv.com",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        _id: "2",
        age: "21",
        chatInfo: [
            {
                chatId: "22",
                createdAt: "2020-07-07T20:08:33.171Z",
                seen: false,
                senderEmail: "debot73186@klefv.com",
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

**Update**

I tried this with underscore

```
const sorting = (arr)=>  {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const user = arr[i];
        user.chatInfo.sort((a, b) => {
            return new Date(a.createdAt).getTime() - new Date(b.createdAt).getTime();
        });
    }
    return _.sortBy(arr, "chatInfo");
}
```

Comment: `chantInfo` is an Array. If it's an Array, it means that multiple elements can be in there (or there would be no reason to have an Array here). You did not include an example or a description of the behavior that should happen if there were multiple elements in there, with different dates. Please include these details. Also, did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort elements of JavaScript arrays using the built-in [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method. In order for it to work as intended, we need to compare the the ISO timestamps by its numerical value.

You can easily construct [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) objects with an ISO timestamp string. Using the [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method will return its numerical representation in milliseconds. The milliseconds can then be compared in a basic sort function.

```
yourArray.sort((a, b) => {
  return new Date(a.chatInfo[0].createdAt).getTime() < new Date(b.chatInfo[0].createdAt).getTime() ? -1 : 1
});
```

Depending on whether you need it sorted in ascending or descending order, simply flip the comparison operator to and from `<` and `>`.